In cpp, return cause std::vector value changed
Following is my code
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "onnx_helper.h"
#include "vector_helper.h"
#include "opencv_helper.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

    class OnnxTest : public testing::Test {
    protected:
    //    static void SetUpTestCase() {
    //    }
    };
    
    Ndarray<float> i2t2(const std::string &img_path) {// Load the image using OpenCV
        cv::Mat input_mat = cv::imread(img_path);
    
        // Convert to float
        cv::cvtColor(input_mat, input_mat, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
        input_mat.convertTo(input_mat, CV_32F);
    
        // Normalize
        input_mat /= 255.0;
    
        // Convert the preprocessed image to a vector of floats
        Ndarray<float> input_img = mat_to_ndarray(input_mat);
    
        // Transpose and expand dimensions
        input_img.transpose({2, 0, 1});
        input_img.expand_dims(0);
        return input_img;
    }
    
    // Assuming you have already defined the necessary functions for image preprocessing
    Ort::Value i2t(const std::string &img_path) {
        Ndarray<float> input_img = i2t2(img_path);
    
        // Create the input tensor
        auto input_vector = input_img.data;
        auto input_shape = input_img.shape;
        return Ort::Value::CreateTensor<float>(
                mem_info,
                input_vector.data(),
                input_vector.size(),
                input_shape.data(),
                input_shape.size());
    }
    
    
    TEST_F(OnnxTest, run_onnx) {
        // Define paths
        auto d = "/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp_lib/test/fix/onnx";
        std::string onnx_model_path = std::format("{}/RealESRGAN_x4plus_anime_6B.onnx", d);
        std::string input_img_path = std::format("{}/small.jpg", d);
        const std::string &out_img_path = std::format("/tmp/t.jpg", d);
    
        // Run inference
        auto s = new_session(onnx_model_path);
    
        auto tensor = i2t(input_img_path);
    
    //    Ndarray<float> input_img = i2t2(input_img_path);
    //    // Create the input tensor
    ////    auto mem_info = Ort::MemoryInfo::CreateCpu(OrtAllocatorType::OrtArenaAllocator,
    ////                                               OrtMemType::OrtMemTypeDefault);
    //    auto input_vector = input_img.data;
    //    auto input_shape = input_img.shape;
    //    auto tensor = Ort::Value::CreateTensor<float>(
    //            mem_info,
    //            input_vector.data(),
    //            input_vector.size(),
    //            input_shape.data(),
    //            input_shape.size());
    
        Ort::Value out_tensor = infer(s, tensor);
        tensor_to_img(out_tensor, out_img_path);
        std::cout << std::format("Output saved to {}", out_img_path) << std::endl;
    }

When I use clion and set breakpoint in return CreateTensor, it's very strange return cause input_vector and input_shape change(see my following gif)

If I don't use meth but use create tensor code in main, the input_vector and input_shape keep old value

this err cause I get wrong tensor and get wrong result, how to fix it

When I see Ort::Value::CreateTensor and it's prototype I can sense dangling pointers issue (pointer obtained from local object that gets invalidated after the return)

@KIIV can you elaborate ? as long as the tensor is returned by value, I don't see any reason for dangling pointer issues.

@wohlstad it is returned by value, but what about those two buffers passed as a pairs of pointer and size? Unless it does a deep copy internally it won't work

@KIIV now I see what you meant. And since the documentation mentions "Creates a tensor with a user supplied buffer." I suspect deep copy is not done (but I am not familiar with this library to know for certain).

Title says "std::vector". Where it is in code provided?

dont use meth :/. Is this supposed to be short for "method" ? We call member functions "methods", but even for those "member function" is the more common term.

From the documentation:
Create tensor:

Creates a tensor with a user supplied buffer. Wraps
OrtApi::CreateTensorWithDataAsOrtValue.

CreateTensorWithDataAsOrtValue:

Create a tensor backed by a user supplied buffer.
Create a tensor with user's buffer. You can fill the buffer either before calling this function or after. p_data is owned by caller.
ReleaseValue won't release p_data.

In your code:
Ort::Value i2t(const std::string &img_path) {
    Ndarray<float> input_img = i2t2(img_path);

    // Create the input tensor
    auto input_vector = input_img.data;
    auto input_shape = input_img.shape;
    return Ort::Value::CreateTensor<float>(
            mem_info,
            input_vector.data(),  // passing buffer owned by local variable
            input_vector.size(),
            input_shape.data(),   // passing buffer owned by local variable
            input_shape.size());

     // after the return statement local variables are deleted and passed buffers are now dangling pointers
}

In short commented out code works because local variables are still valid (as it's the same scope) and function doesn't as scope of those local variables ended after the return statement
